# What is the maximum field length sql will sort? for varchar or nvarchar

Tags: sql-server

Hey guys I thought I ran into something where sql would only sort up to a certain length of a varchar or nvarchar. Does anyone know that #?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, there is a limit of 8,060
>   bytes for the row size of intermediate
>   worktables needed for sort operations.
>   This limits the total size of columns
>   specified in an ORDER BY clause.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

If you are hitting that length, you have bigger problems!

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation dependent

- [Fast searching of large (n)varchar values](http://www.sqlservernation.com/home/fast-searching-of-large-nvarchar-values.html)

  - [Hashing large data strings with a User Defined Function](http://www.sqlservernation.com/home/hashing-large-data-strings-with-a-user-defined-function.html)

you can order by some (hashing, checksum, whatever) function (which reduces the size to sortable one) from column values being ordered